# Menu bar clock disappears during certain times of the day

Tags: clock

I'm running Mavericks on a 2013 MacBook Air. Every time my clock reaches 10:00 (both AM and PM) it disappears, then reappears again once it reaches 12:00/0:00. I have it set as a 12 hour clock.

I found a way to temporarily fix it, by switching to analogue and then back again, however the next time 10:00 AM/PM comes around, it disappears again.

Is there any way to fix this permanently?

Comment: On what device and which OS version?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about a Mac: are you running any programs that do something with your menu bar, such as Bartender? Does this same issue occur in a guest account or in Safe Mode?

Comment: Some more potentially enlightening questions: What screen resolution are you using? Does the clock reappear exactly at 12:00? You say it disappears at 10 AM and PM — when on 24 hour time does it disappear at 20:00 or 22:00?

Comment: When you say it disappears, do you mean there is a blank space where it should be, or do the other things in your menu bar take its place? Could you post a screenshot, or a pair of them showing before/after?